# Uniform Distribution in Unit Disk

Tags: probability

Assume you choose randomly two points $A,B$ in the unit disk.
Let $R_1$ be the distance of $A$ from $(0,0)$.
Let $R_2$ be the distance of $B$ from $(0,0)$.

how would you calculate $P(R_1>2R_2)$?

thanks.

Comment: It's $\|frac{1}{2}$, by symmetry.

Comment: @gnometorule No it's not. I think you missed the factor of two.

Comment: what do you mean by frac? I dont get this word..

Comment: @adamco it's a LaTeX command for fraction. But he's wrong anyway...

Comment: thanks for all the comments, but can anyone guide me to the answer and not give me one? thanks again.

Comment: I did miss the factor of $2$ (and my phone didn't let me edit the latex typo).

Comment: @JonathanChristensen While I understand the confusion I was having, the unit circle can be thought of as a set of coordinates, coordinates are _in_ sets. So it's not stupid at all, just trying to explain my reasoning.

Comment: @RustynYazdanpour I wasn't saying your confusion was stupid (sorry!), was saying it would be a stupid question if we were in fact interested in the unit circle, since the probability would trivially be zero, as you showed.

Comment: any guidance to the answer please?

Comment: @JonathanChristensen You're absolutely right, I totally agree with you now.

Comment: @mezhang: I rejected your suggested edit that interpolated the words "uniformly and independently" into the answer. Instead of changing the meaning of the text, you should leave a comment instead, even if it seems obvious to you what is meant.

Comment: @adamco: The question is incomplete without specifying the distribution of $A$ and $B$. Did you mean that they are chosen uniformly and independently on the unit disk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you solve the problem:

1. Find $P(R_1 > 2R_2 | R_1)$ for a fixed value of $R_1$. This will be a function of $R_1$, call it $g(R_1)$. Remember that since the points are distributed uniformly on the disc, probability is proportionate to area. This is pretty easy.
2. Find the density function of $R_1$, call it $f(R_1)$.
3. Finally, integrate the function you found in part (1) over the distribution you found in part (2) to find the marginal probability $P(R_1 > 2R_2)$:
   $$P(R_1 > 2R_2) = \int_0^1 g(R_1) f(R_1) \, dR_1.$$

Comment: how would you find the distribution of R1?

Comment: @adamco Easiest via the CDF: There's a nice closed form for $P(R_1 \leq r)$. Then differentiate to find the pdf.